# Unsigned Character array issues

Tags: python, c++

I have working C++ code that bit shifts a bit font. I am trying to get a Python code to do the same. Thank you for any help.
I am re-writing my question to simplify it to exactly what I think I need.
Thank you all so much for your time and instructions.

In C++ I can create:

```
unsigned char   vals[8][8] = {0};
```

Which gives me an 8 X 8 array filled with 0's ... the {0} representing vals[0][0]

and the array going to vals[7][7]

In my C++ code, I populate the vals array with bit-font values and then I shift the values <<= 1 , example:

```
vals[5][3] <<= 1
```

I need this same unsigned char 2D array in Python and to be able to shift the values in the Python array (loaded with the same values that are in the C++ array) and get the same shifted values from the Python array that I get from the C++ array.

I have had no success with any Python array providing the same values as the C++. I need help getting

```
unsigned char   vals[8][8] = {0};
```

into Python.
I have tried to create and populate different arrays, dictionaries, lists but I have had no success.

I want to add that this is a working copy of C++ that I am trying to achieve in Python. This can be compiled.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define STRING               "12345678"
unsigned char *text = STRING;

const unsigned char TEST_FONT[128][8] = {
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 },
        { 0x00, 0x3E, 0x41, 0x55, 0x41, 0x55, 0x49, 0x3E },
        { 0x00, 0x3E, 0x7F, 0x6B, 0x7F, 0x6B, 0x77, 0x3E },
        { 0x00, 0x22, 0x77, 0x7F, 0x7F, 0x3E, 0x1C, 0x08 },
        { 0x00, 0x08, 0x1C, 0x3E, 0x7F, 0x3E, 0x1C, 0x08 },
        { 0x00, 0x08, 0x1C, 0x2A, 0x7F, 0x2A, 0x08, 0x1C },
        { 0x00, 0x08, 0x1C, 0x3E, 0x7F, 0x3E, 0x08, 0x1C },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x1C, 0x3E, 0x3E, 0x3E, 0x1C, 0x00 },
        { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xE3, 0xC1, 0xC1, 0xC1, 0xE3, 0xFF },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x1C, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x1C, 0x00 },
        { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xE3, 0xDD, 0xDD, 0xDD, 0xE3, 0xFF },
        { 0x00, 0x0F, 0x03, 0x05, 0x39, 0x48, 0x48, 0x30 },
        { 0x00, 0x08, 0x3E, 0x08, 0x1C, 0x22, 0x22, 0x1C },
        { 0x00, 0x18, 0x14, 0x10, 0x10, 0x30, 0x70, 0x60 },
        { 0x00, 0x0F, 0x19, 0x11, 0x13, 0x37, 0x76, 0x60 },
        { 0x00, 0x08, 0x2A, 0x1C, 0x77, 0x1C, 0x2A, 0x08 },
        { 0x00, 0x60, 0x78, 0x7E, 0x7F, 0x7E, 0x78, 0x60 },
        { 0x00, 0x03, 0x0F, 0x3F, 0x7F, 0x3F, 0x0F, 0x03 },
        { 0x00, 0x08, 0x1C, 0x2A, 0x08, 0x2A, 0x1C, 0x08 },
        { 0x00, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x00, 0x66, 0x66 },
        { 0x00, 0x3F, 0x65, 0x65, 0x3D, 0x05, 0x05, 0x05 },
        { 0x00, 0x0C, 0x32, 0x48, 0x24, 0x12, 0x4C, 0x30 },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7F, 0x7F, 0x7F },
        { 0x00, 0x08, 0x1C, 0x2A, 0x08, 0x2A, 0x1C, 0x3E },
        { 0x00, 0x08, 0x1C, 0x3E, 0x7F, 0x1C, 0x1C, 0x1C },
        { 0x00, 0x1C, 0x1C, 0x1C, 0x7F, 0x3E, 0x1C, 0x08 },
        { 0x00, 0x08, 0x0C, 0x7E, 0x7F, 0x7E, 0x0C, 0x08 },
        { 0x00, 0x08, 0x18, 0x3F, 0x7F, 0x3F, 0x18, 0x08 },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x7F, 0x7F },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x14, 0x22, 0x7F, 0x22, 0x14, 0x00 },
        { 0x00, 0x08, 0x1C, 0x1C, 0x3E, 0x3E, 0x7F, 0x7F },
        { 0x00, 0x7F, 0x7F, 0x3E, 0x3E, 0x1C, 0x1C, 0x08 },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 },
        { 0x00, 0x18, 0x3C, 0x3C, 0x18, 0x18, 0x00, 0x18 },
        { 0x00, 0x36, 0x36, 0x14, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 },
        { 0x00, 0x36, 0x36, 0x7F, 0x36, 0x7F, 0x36, 0x36 },
        { 0x00, 0x08, 0x1E, 0x20, 0x1C, 0x02, 0x3C, 0x08 },
        { 0x00, 0x60, 0x66, 0x0C, 0x18, 0x30, 0x66, 0x06 },
        { 0x00, 0x3C, 0x66, 0x3C, 0x28, 0x65, 0x66, 0x3F },
        { 0x00, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x30, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 },
        { 0x00, 0x06, 0x0C, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x0C, 0x06 },
        { 0x00, 0x60, 0x30, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x30, 0x60 },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x36, 0x1C, 0x7F, 0x1C, 0x36, 0x00 },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x08, 0x3E, 0x08, 0x08, 0x00 },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x60 },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x60, 0x60 },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x0C, 0x18, 0x30, 0x60, 0x00 },
        { 0x00, 0x3C, 0x66, 0x6E, 0x76, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3C },
        { 0x00, 0x18, 0x18, 0x38, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x7E },
        { 0x00, 0x3C, 0x66, 0x06, 0x0C, 0x30, 0x60, 0x7E },
        { 0x00, 0x3C, 0x66, 0x06, 0x1C, 0x06, 0x66, 0x3C },
        { 0x00, 0x0C, 0x1C, 0x2C, 0x4C, 0x7E, 0x0C, 0x0C },
        { 0x00, 0x7E, 0x60, 0x7C, 0x06, 0x06, 0x66, 0x3C },
        { 0x00, 0x3C, 0x66, 0x60, 0x7C, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3C },
        { 0x00, 0x7E, 0x66, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18 },
        { 0x00, 0x3C, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3C, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3C },
        { 0x00, 0x3C, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3E, 0x06, 0x66, 0x3C },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x18, 0x00, 0x18, 0x18, 0x00 },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x18, 0x00, 0x18, 0x18, 0x30 },
        { 0x00, 0x06, 0x0C, 0x18, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0C, 0x06 },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3C, 0x00, 0x3C, 0x00, 0x00 },
        { 0x00, 0x60, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0C, 0x18, 0x30, 0x60 },
        { 0x00, 0x3C, 0x66, 0x06, 0x1C, 0x18, 0x00, 0x18 },
        { 0x00, 0x38, 0x44, 0x5C, 0x58, 0x42, 0x3C, 0x00 },
        { 0x00, 0x3C, 0x66, 0x66, 0x7E, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66 },
        { 0x00, 0x7C, 0x66, 0x66, 0x7C, 0x66, 0x66, 0x7C },
        { 0x00, 0x3C, 0x66, 0x60, 0x60, 0x60, 0x66, 0x3C },
        { 0x00, 0x7C, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x7C },
        { 0x00, 0x7E, 0x60, 0x60, 0x7C, 0x60, 0x60, 0x7E },
        { 0x00, 0x7E, 0x60, 0x60, 0x7C, 0x60, 0x60, 0x60 },
        { 0x00, 0x3C, 0x66, 0x60, 0x60, 0x6E, 0x66, 0x3C },
        { 0x00, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x7E, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66 },
        { 0x00, 0x3C, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x3C },
        { 0x00, 0x1E, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x38 },
        { 0x00, 0x66, 0x6C, 0x78, 0x70, 0x78, 0x6C, 0x66 },
        { 0x00, 0x60, 0x60, 0x60, 0x60, 0x60, 0x60, 0x7E },
        { 0x00, 0x63, 0x77, 0x7F, 0x6B, 0x63, 0x63, 0x63 },
        { 0x00, 0x63, 0x73, 0x7B, 0x6F, 0x67, 0x63, 0x63 },
        { 0x00, 0x3C, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3C },
        { 0x00, 0x7C, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x7C, 0x60, 0x60 },
        { 0x00, 0x3C, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x6E, 0x3C, 0x06 },
        { 0x00, 0x7C, 0x66, 0x66, 0x7C, 0x78, 0x6C, 0x66 },
        { 0x00, 0x3C, 0x66, 0x60, 0x3C, 0x06, 0x66, 0x3C },
        { 0x00, 0x7E, 0x5A, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18 },
        { 0x00, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3E },
        { 0x00, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3C, 0x18 },
        { 0x00, 0x63, 0x63, 0x63, 0x6B, 0x7F, 0x77, 0x63 },
        { 0x00, 0x63, 0x63, 0x36, 0x1C, 0x36, 0x63, 0x63 },
        { 0x00, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3C, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18 },
        { 0x00, 0x7E, 0x06, 0x0C, 0x18, 0x30, 0x60, 0x7E },
        { 0x00, 0x1E, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x1E },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x60, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0C, 0x06, 0x00 },
        { 0x00, 0x78, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x78 },
        { 0x00, 0x08, 0x14, 0x22, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7F },
        { 0x00, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3C, 0x06, 0x3E, 0x66, 0x3E },
        { 0x00, 0x60, 0x60, 0x60, 0x7C, 0x66, 0x66, 0x7C },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3C, 0x66, 0x60, 0x66, 0x3C },
        { 0x00, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x3E, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3E },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3C, 0x66, 0x7E, 0x60, 0x3C },
        { 0x00, 0x1C, 0x36, 0x30, 0x30, 0x7C, 0x30, 0x30 },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x3E, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3E, 0x06, 0x3C },
        { 0x00, 0x60, 0x60, 0x60, 0x7C, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66 },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x00, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x3C },
        { 0x00, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x38 },
        { 0x00, 0x60, 0x60, 0x66, 0x6C, 0x78, 0x6C, 0x66 },
        { 0x00, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18 },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x63, 0x77, 0x7F, 0x6B, 0x6B },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7C, 0x7E, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66 },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3C, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3C },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x7C, 0x66, 0x66, 0x7C, 0x60, 0x60 },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x3C, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x3C, 0x0D, 0x0F },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7C, 0x66, 0x66, 0x60, 0x60 },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3E, 0x40, 0x3C, 0x02, 0x7C },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x18, 0x7E, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18 },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3E },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3C, 0x18 },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x63, 0x6B, 0x6B, 0x6B, 0x3E },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x66, 0x3C, 0x18, 0x3C, 0x66 },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3E, 0x06, 0x3C },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3C, 0x0C, 0x18, 0x30, 0x3C },
        { 0x00, 0x0E, 0x18, 0x18, 0x30, 0x18, 0x18, 0x0E },
        { 0x00, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x00, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18 },
        { 0x00, 0x70, 0x18, 0x18, 0x0C, 0x18, 0x18, 0x70 },
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3A, 0x6C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 },
        { 0x00, 0x08, 0x1C, 0x36, 0x63, 0x41, 0x41, 0x7F }
};

#define FONT    TEST_FONT
int length = 8;
unsigned char   vals[8][8] = { 0 };

void font_update(unsigned char *loc)
{
    int     i, j, x = 0, pos = 0;
    while(*loc != 0x00) {
        for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)  {
            vals[pos][i] = FONT[*loc][i];
        }
        pos++; loc++;
    }
    while(x < 4) {
        for(j = 0; j < length; j++)   {
            for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)  {
                printf (" Shift Before Vals[%d][%d] = %d \n",j,i,vals[j][i]);
                vals[j][i] <<= 1;
                printf (" Shift After Vals[%d][%d] = %d \n",j,i,vals[j][i]);
                //an "if" block is not provided the curly braces then only 1 statement is considered inside it.
                if((j != length -1) && (vals[j + 1][i] & 0x80)) {
                    vals[j][i] |= 0x01;
                    printf (" Length Update Vals[%d][%d] = %d \n",j,i,vals[j][i]);
                }
            printf ("\n");
            }
        }
        x++;
    }
};

int main ()
{

int x;
    for(x=0; x < 5; x++) {
      font_update(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Python integer has infinite length.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the question but presumably you just need to and your values with `0xFF`, e.g: `char = vals[i][j] & 0xFF`

Comment: Thanks Alan, I have the array vals in the c++ filled with bit-font values, i.e.         [ 0x00, 0x3C, 0x66, 0x06, 0x0C, 0x30, 0x60, 0x7E ],
        [ 0x00, 0x3C, 0x66, 0x06, 0x1C, 0x06, 0x66, 0x3C ],
        [ 0x00, 0x0C, 0x1C, 0x2C, 0x4C, 0x7E, 0x0C, 0x0C ],
        [ 0x00, 0x7E, 0x60, 0x7C, 0x06, 0x06, 0x66, 0x3C ],
        [ 0x00, 0x3C, 0x66, 0x60, 0x7C, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3C ],
        [ 0x00, 0x7E, 0x66, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18 ],
        [ 0x00, 0x3C, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3C, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3C ], and the shift updates them <<= 1 them

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. All that code from which to pick your misunderstanding isn't useful. It makes this a bad question and even off-topic.

Comment: Ulrich, I updated my question... I hope is more understandable. Thank You. I think and hope it is minimal, complete and verifiable.

Comment: font is not defined. vals is defined and then overwritten a few times. Inconsistent use of "length" or hardcoded 8 (in c++ and python).

Comment: similar problems in c++ code snippet. Will not compile. Also, both languages support better containers and iteration practices. Maybe you should focus on code that demonstrates one specific bit shift that doesn't produce what you expected. Delete all the stuff about why you want to shift if it doesn't matter.

Comment: Is this just a problem with the carry, if you shift multibyte structures as if they were single bytes?

Comment: Your question is just as unclear and overloaded as it was. Further, now you address me in the question ussing some injected fragments of a sentence, which will just confuse even more. Please delete your question and first read the provided link. Also, you probably need to revisit [ask], too.

Comment: I have rephrased my question. Hopefully this will make it more understandable. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I just added a working C++ example. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use `NumPy` and ndarrays of specified type - e.g.

```
import numpy as np

np.full(shape=8, fill_value=0, dtype=np.int8) # or np.zeros()
```

Contrary to default Python `int` handling (which as iBug pointed out in the comment - is infinite length) you will end up with a integer values of very specific bit-length. Shifting these will give you the behaviour similar to C++.

Comment: Thanks sophros, I will give this a try.

Comment: Hello sophros ! This appears to have worked and the numpy array I believe is returning correct values! Now I need to incorporate all of this into my Python and I am optimistic! Thanks for your help and insight.